# How does Vim opens big files so fast ?

Tags: vim, file-handling

I opened a PDF file in vim which was about 4MB and it opened it at the blink of eye. I was amazed at the speed. So I tried the same in notepad and it crashed. I tried in notepad++, it took time.

Does anyone knows how vim handles this scenarios ? What makes reading files in vim so fast ?

Comment: opening a file is fast, regardless of the size of the file.  Reading it is only slow if you try to read the whole file.  Presumably, vim doesn't read too much, while the other editors attempt to read the entire file before displaying anything.

Comment: 4MB is not "big" at all. Try a 2GB log file and see if Vim is as snappy as with your 4MB PDF.

Comment: Opening files with a high amount of lines is fast in vim - as others said. But if you have a large file where the lines are very long vim can have trouble with that.

Comment: to make it more faster you can abort the buffer file while opening the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vim reads the whole file into an internal *buffer* on opening, so this all depends on your (virtual) memory and overall computer performance. Some *disk editors* only read in (viewed) parts of the file dynamically, and thereby obtain even greater performance.

On todays hardware, 4 MB is nothing. You can still drag down Vim with files of 100s of MB, especially if long lines or syntax highlighting is involved.

Other editors should not have a problem with 4 MB, neither. But PDF is not a text format, it's binary, so that might have confused some editors or taken them a long time to figure out what it's about.

The [LargeFile plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1506) is worth mentioning here.

Comment: I would have guessed vim would simply mmap the file (at least on unix) preventing it to read the whole file.